# SSIS package 2012

Tags: ssis, package

I have attached the screen shot

How to use the check points in SSIS 2012 package in order to restart the package from point of failure not from the beginning.

I think its not allowing me to attach the image...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Checkpoints](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-tools/implementing-checkpoints-in-an-ssis-package/) which basically  executes the package from the point where it got failed.If your package has 5 to 6 steps and if the 2nd step failed  then the next time when u execute the package it will start from 2nd step .

You can refer these blogs [31 days of SSIS](http://www.jasonstrate.com/2011/01/31-days-of-ssis-the-introduction/) and  articles from [Simple Talk](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/)

Update :-

Step1: Right click on Control Flow and select properties.

Step2: Specify the informations for CheckPointFileName, CheckpointUsage and SaveCheckPoints

[image]

CheckPointFileName = Points to the XML file location where checkpoint details will be stored by SSIS

CheckpointUsage =Specifies 3 properties (`Never,IfExists,Always`)
Never signifies that the checkpoints will never be used.

`IfExists` = Checkpoints will be used if a file exists

`Always`=A checkpoint file will always be used .If the file is missing then error will be thrown

`SavecheckPoints` =Set it true to save the checkpoints

Now for all the controls or tasks  set `FailPackageOnFailure`  property to `True` for the components which you want to participate in Checkpoints . This property `indicates whether the package fails when the execution fails`

[image]

Comment: Thanks praveen for your help,please can you guide me how to setup the checkpoints to steps in package as am newer to the BIDS and its not clear with the link you provided

Comment: here images are not clear what should be the CheckpointFileName,if i click on eclipse buttion its asking me to browse..

Comment: Just create an empty file like Checkpoints.xml and point this file

Comment: ok,FailPackageOnFailure property am not getting by right clicking on the controls from Data flow.

Comment: if i sets the checkpoints my package is not exectuing,its states message as successfully compelted but where as data is not inserting into the table in db

Comment: Praveen ,can you please help me why my package is not exectuing if i set the check point usage to ture but the package result output says that package completed successfully.

Comment: Without checkpoints was it executing properly ? n can u show ur package design becuase without actually seeing your package i cannot comment or resolve the issue

Comment: yes without checkpoints package is exectuing as expected and getting the results,how to show the package design to u i mean can i attach screen shot?

Comment: Yes you can attach a screenshot of your SSIS package .http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: i have attached the screen shot

Comment: @user2315732: You have removed your entire question and moreover there is no image attached

Comment: Its not allowing to attach the image it says that not enough reputation.

Comment: hi praveen can you please help me to understand the behaviour of the checkpoints option...